# Utilização de teclas de setas para gerar movimento em jogo

Tags: c, c++

Eu queria saber como o desenvolvedor do game Snake em C++ mesclado com C fez a cobra se mover a partir das setas do teclado.

Eu acho que a parte em que se move é na hora que compara `tecla=='K'` `tecla=='H'` e assim por diante, mas eu queria saber porque ele usou essas letras, e o principal.

Por que quando aperta a seta que por acaso não são essas letras a cobra se move?

Aqui vai o código

```
  #include<windows.h>
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<conio.h>
  #include<iostream>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <time.h>


  //Código feito com base em tutoriais na internet, desenvolvido por  
  Gustavo    Ferreira do 2 semestre do Curso de Jogos Digitais da FATEC   
  SAO CAETANO DO SUL.

  void mgotoxy(int x, int y)
  {
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),(COORD)          
  {x,y});//Percorre a matriz    
  }

  main() 
  {
  int x,d=2,cx[300]={1,2},cy[300]={7,7},t=1,mx,my,velo=100,velo2=5;
  char niv;

  char tecla='a';
  int opcao;
  int pontos=0;
  int nivel = 1;



  for(x=0;x<18;x++)
  { mgotoxy(0,x); //vertical esquerda.//

  printf("%c",219);
  }
  for(x=0;x<50;x++)
  { mgotoxy(x,0); //horizontal superior//
  printf("%c",219);
  }
  for(x=0;x<18;x++)
  { mgotoxy(50,x); //vertical direita//
   printf("%c",219);
  }
  for(x=0;x<51;x++)
  { mgotoxy(x,18); //horizontal inferior.//
  printf("%c",219);
   }

  srand(time(NULL));
  mx=(rand()%49)+1;
  my=(rand()%17)+1;

  velo = 200;

  while(tecla!='s')
  { while(tecla!='s'&&!(tecla=kbhit()))

  { for(x=t;x>0;x--)
  { cx[x]=cx[x-1];
  cy[x]=cy[x-1];
   }

  if(d==0)cx[0]--;
  if(d==1)cy[0]--;
  if(d==2)cx[0]++;
  if(d==3)cy[0]++;
  mgotoxy(cx[t],cy[t]);
  printf(" ");
  if(mx==cx[0]&&my==cy[0])
  { t++;
  pontos++;
  mx=(rand()%25)+1;
  my=(rand()%17)+1;
  velo-=5;
  velo2+=5;

    }
   mgotoxy(cx[0],cy[0]);

   printf("%c",219);

   mgotoxy(mx,my);
   printf("%c",1);
   mgotoxy(55,10);

   printf ("Pontos: %d",pontos);
   mgotoxy(55,5);
   printf ("Nivel: %d",nivel);
   mgotoxy(55,3);
   printf ("Velocidade: %d",velo2);
   mgotoxy(3,22);

   printf ("Jogo desenvolvido por Gustavo Ferreira");
   Sleep(velo);
   for(x=1;x<t;x++)
   { if(cx[0]==cx[x]&&cy[0]==cy[x])tecla='s';
   }
   if(cy[0]==0||cy[0]==18||cx[0]==0||cx[0]==50)tecla='s';

     }
   if(tecla!='s')tecla=getch();
   printf("%c",tecla);
   if(tecla=='K')d=0;
   if(tecla=='H')d=1;
   if(tecla=='M')d=2;
   if(tecla=='P')d=3;
   if(cy[0]==0||cy[0]==18||cx[0]==0||cx[0]==26)tecla='s';

  }
 system("cls");
 system("pause");

 printf ("\n\n\tVOCE PERDEU\n\n");

 printf ("\n\n\tVOCE FEZ %d PONTOS",pontos);







   getch();
    }
```

Comment: Por que ele escolheu 'H' e 'K'? Por que ele não deve ser muito da área dos games, do contrario teria utilizado "AWDS".

Comment: Não tenho condição de executar esse código aqui(nem quero baixar uma ide/compilador). Me mata uma curiosidade, como esse código funciona? A "cobra" anda sozinha, ou só quando você pressiona uma tecla? Pois uma vez fiz algo parecido e ler uma tecla em um loop sem fazer o terminal bloquear  foi um "parto" rsrsrs.

Comment: Não é isso que estou dizendo... vamos supor se eu aperto a seta pra cima o programa entende que eu apertei 'K' não sei como isso acontece se quiser compile e veja, o jogo é na seta mesmo

Comment: @mauhumor se você inicia o lado que ela vai ir ela anda sozinha até tomar outra decisão, como mostra essa parte do código while(tecla!='s')
  { while(tecla!='s'&&!(tecla=kbhit()))

Comment: Tá me pedindo para interpretar o código do sujeito, Isso é complicado. Cada um tem sua lógica e forma especifica de resolver um problema. E entender como outra pessoa fez nem sempre é fácil, mesmo com anos de experiência em uma linguagem ou tecnologia. E eu arreguei para este código :/.

Comment: Talvez amanhã, rsrsrs. Boa noite :D

Comment: Olá Anderson. Bem vindo ao SOPT. Antes de mais nada, observe que este site não é um fórum (faça o [tour] e leia [ask]). Jogar um código de outra pessoa na sua pergunta e comentar "compile aí e veja" não vai te ajudar a ter respostas úteis, ok?

Comment: Bom, o "porquê" do autor ter usado as letras é meramente uma escolha. Pra ter a resposta certa, você vai ter que perguntar ao autor. Como o colega @mauhumor [bem comentou](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177384/utiliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-teclas-de-setas-para-gerar-movimento-em-jogo#comment366307_177384), esse **não é** o padrão utilizado em jogos.

Comment: Sobre como funciona a movimentação, ela não depende das teclas. As teclas apenas controlam a direção. Esse código está *muito mal organizado*, então é difícil de saber com certeza só de olhar. Mas me parece o seguinte: basicamente a função `mgotoxy` é a responsável pelo posicionamento; o laço `while` faz a cobra se mover sozinha conforme duas variáveis, a direção (`d`) e a velocidade (`velo` e `velo2` - sei lá por que o autor usa duas variáveis, e não parei pra analisar em detalhes); as teclas só mudam a direção (isto é, alteram a variável `d`).

Comment: Se você quer saber *exatamente* como esse código funciona, compile-o e depure-o *você mesmo*. Não vai adiantar muito vir perguntar aqui. Agora, se você quer aprender como se faz um jogo de uma forma decente, sinto dizer mas não vai ser analisando esse código. Procure um bom [livro](http://gamedeveloper.com.br/livros-de-desenvolvimento-de-jogos/) ou [curso](http://gamereporter.uol.com.br/desenvolvimento-de-jogos-digitais/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este código tem nada C++, é bem ruim e eu não perderia tempo com ele. Aprenda com códigos bons. Ele usa técnicas ruins, estilo ruim, é confuso, usa o que não estão disponíveis em todos os compiladores, duvido que faça o que foi pensado e tem erros, na verdade ele nem compila.

As teclas permitidas são `K`, `H`, `M`, `P`.

No compilador específico que ele usou, e provavelmente só nele, essas teclas tem o mesmo código das teclas de setas e por isso a escolha deve ter sido feita, a intenção não é usá-las e sim usar as setas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: +1 pela boa resposta. Mas uma curiosidade: como você inferiu o compilador que ele usou? Se tiverem o mesmo código das setas, a escolha passa a fazer um pouco mais de sentido. Mas não seria estranho elas terem o mesmo código?

Comment: @LuizVieira eu não inferi qual é o compilador. Apenas que no compilador dele deve funcionar isso :) Tem compilador que realmente mistura códigos de teclas, mas é fora de padrão. E por compilador, entenda a biblioteca dele. Esclarecido? Acho que iria gostar desta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177611/101 mas ele ficou escondida pelos negativos. Falei certo? :)

Comment: Ah, sim. Obrigado! É só que eu fiquei curioso mesmo (e como você manja muito mais do que eu nesses meandros eu achei que podia aprender algo novo). :)

Comment: @LuizVieira muito pelo contrário :D