# Afinal por que usar C quando se está programando em C++?

Tags: c, c++, característica-linguagem, estilo-de-codificação

Estou aprendendo C++ e eu não consigo entender porque as pessoas acham que quem sabe C sabe C++? Ou será que as diferenças entre as duas são desprezíveis?

Sei que a sintaxe é parecida, mas C++14 faz coisas que o C não faz, e fora que a sintaxe do C++14 as vezes pode estar errada no C e vice versa.

A pergunta mesmo é se a diferença pode ser desprezada?

Vamos supor meu amigo programa em C eu programo em C++ se eu tentar compilar o programa dele no C++ tem uma grande chance de o compilador achar um monte de erros de sintaxe. Bjarne disse no livro dele que C++ é como se fosse uma expansão do C e orientada a objetos, mas a sintaxe de algumas coisas que você pode fazer no C não dá pra fazer no C++.

Até onde eu li no livro do Bjarne no começo o C++ foi considerado tipo um C com classes, e com as versões ele vem ficando um pouco mais distante do C, tipo com array. Depois que eu aprendi a usar vetor no C++ eu prefiro usar vetor, pois não tenho que declarar um tamanho fixo, já com arrays o C++ não funciona bem se você não declarar o tamanho da array, não dá pra declarar uma `int arr[linha][coluna]` no C++, isso é só um exemplo, parece que atualmente em algumas versões do C++ não dá pra usar 100% duma sintaxe do C pois vai dar erro.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Por que escolher C ao invés de C++ ou então C++ no lugar de C?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19073/por-que-escolher-c-ao-inv%c3%a9s-de-c-ou-ent%c3%a3o-c-no-lugar-de-c)

Comment: Nao entendi direito a pergunta. C++14 é versão, aí já misturou versão com linguagem. C também tem versões. Tem coisa que o C++14 faz que versões anteriores do próprio C++ não fazem. Seria legal [edit] e deixar mais clara a dúvida exata. E esse negócio de tem coisa que uma faz e outra não faz, não tem muito sentido pra mim. Desconheço coisa que não possa ser feita em qualquer uma delas. Se está falando de coisa pronta na sintaxe da linguagem, compensa [edit] e explicar melhor. Obviamente que se for questão de sintaxe toda linguagem faz "coisas que a outra não faz".

Comment: Minha maior dúvida é pq vi aqui que gente que sabe C acha que sabe C++ e depois fala que são linguagens diferentes.

Comment: O que o C não faz? C++ é um C otimizado, o que não significa que ele faça coisas que o C não possa fazer também.

Comment: Isso dos arrays e vetores é besteria. O `C` nao tem vetores, mas voce pode fazer os seus se quiser.  A seguinte linha compila em `c++` e em `c`. `int matrix[2][2] = { {1,2}, {3,4} };`. Será que a sua pergunta é a seguinte: "Todo o código que compila em `C` também compila em `C++`?". Talvez essa seria uma pergunta melhor.

Comment: Eu só descobri a pergunta hoje, mas honestamente não entendi o porquê de tanta negativação. Ela está bem escrita, é uma dúvida honesta e justa de um estudante, e ela foi editada pelo autor para ser melhorada. Quem negativou na primeira revisão (se foi o caso), talvez devesse reconsiderar. :)

Comment: O problema de arrays é quando você quer que o usuário defina o tamanho da array, e os dados que vão dentro dela

Comment: @RhuanCarlos acredito que deveria alterar o titulo da sua pergunta, ficou bem confusa, de resto está tudo ok

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Estou aprendendo C++ e eu não consigo entender porque as pessoas acham que quem sabe C sabe C++?

Não posso fazer uma afirmação muito objetiva. Posso confirmar que isso ocorre muito. Posso imaginar que boa parte dos casos é por ignorância mesmo. É mais comum na área do que se imagina. Também pode ser por orgulho/arrogância/teimosia. Muitas pessoas fazem do jeito que querem e não se importam com mais nada. Na verdade, é possível que seja um misto de ambos, porque quem acha que já sabe tudo e não precisa aprender direito em geral são os que menos sabem.

Mas pode ser por pragmatismo também. Eu acho que deve-se programar C++ como C++ e não como C. De maneira geral os bons profissionais de ambas também acham isso. Mas nada impede misturar estilos e em alguns raros casos é possível realmente ter uma vantagem real em fazer C dentro do C++.

> Ou será que as diferenças entre as duas são desprezíveis?

Desprezíveis em termos de sintaxe não é, mas são bem pequenas. Quase tudo que é válido em C padrão é válido em C++ padrão. Já estilo é bem, mas bem diferente mesmo.

> Sei que a sintaxe é parecida, mas C++14 faz coisas que o C não faz, e fora que a sintaxe do C++14 as vezes pode estar errada no C e vice versa.

C++20, C++17, C++14 são compatíveis com C++11, com C++98 e versões anteriores da linguagem. Todas essas versões são 99.9% (número chutado, mas é mais ou menos isso mesmo) compatíveis com C89, 99.8% com C99 e uns 99.6% do C11. Será assim com C++23 e as próximas versões que surgirão. Talvez a compatibilidade de C e C++ diminua um pouco, mas é ínfimo.

Sintaxe específica do C++ não funciona em C, afinal ela é um super conjunto.

Note que tudo que uma linguagem faz, a outra também faz, afinal ambas são [linguagens de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101), e, portanto, Turing Complete. O que existe é uma forma diferente de fazer.

> Vamos supor meu amigo programa em C eu programo em C++ se eu tentar compilar o programa dele no C++ tem uma grande chance de o compilador achar um monte de erros de sintaxe.

De maneira geral não é para ter problemas. As [poucas coisas incompatíveis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B) na verdade nem deveriam ser usadas de qualquer forma. Mas se o código é C, continue mexendo em C. Ou porte totalmente e desista do original. Se colocar algo do C++ nesse código, não poderá mais ser usado como um código C.

> Bjarne disse no livro dele que C++ é como se fosse uma expansão do C e orientada a objetos, mas a sintaxe de algumas coisas que você pode fazer no C não dá pra fazer no C++.

Precisa interpretar o texto, ver os detalhes. É isso mesmo, mas é uma simplificação. No livro tem as poucas diferenças.

> Depois que eu aprendi a usar vetor no C++ eu prefiro usar vetor, pois não tenho que declarar um tamanho fixo.

C++ tem o tipo [`Array`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163424/101) também para tamanho fixo. Costuma ser melhor usá-lo quando é isso que deseja. Obviamente que o *array* do C também funciona. Há casos para usar a forma do C.

> Já com arrays o C++ não funciona bem se você não declarar o tamanho da array

Em C também. Existe uma forma que dá alguma flexibilidade, mas não está disponível em todos os compiladores, é complicado fazer certo e não costuma ser vantajoso. É mais comum a pessoa criar uma estrutura própria ou usar uma biblioteca quando precisa de tamanho variável. C++ tem pronto, nem sempre é o mais adequado.

> Parece que atualmente em algumas versões do C++ não dá pra usar 100% duma sintaxe do C pois vai dar erro.

Sim, 100% não, mas quase isso. Ou 100% do que deveria ser usado de fato em C.

> Minha maior dúvida é porque vi aqui que gente que sabe C acha que sabe C++ e depois fala que são linguagens diferentes.

Quem sabe C sabe uma parte do C++. Se ele programa como deveria em C++ é outra coisa. Mas de fato, é uma confusão comum. Tem gente que pensa que as duas linguagens são a mesma. Outros acham que C++ é um C melhorado, alguns até acham que é otimizado. Há quem ache que é o C orientado a objeto, o que é uma simplificação danosa. Na verdade, são linguagens bem diferentes com **alguma** compatibilidade binária e de sintaxe entre elas.

## Conclusão

C e C++ são linguagens bem diferentes. Com alto grau de compatibilidade, C++ é quase um *superset* de C. Saber C ajuda saber C++, mas é melhor aprender usar a linguagem do zero para pegar o estilo de cada uma. Então na verdade saber C pode atrapalhar aprender C++. Tem muito material por aí, incluindo livros que ensina C++ como se fosse C.

Muita gente fala besteira sobre o assunto e poucas pessoas sabem mesmo programar em uma ou outra e menos ainda nas duas. Eu mesmo não sou profundo conhecedor de ambas, erro nos detalhes, mas não erro no geral. Sempre preciso consultar fontes antes de fazer alguma coisa mais sofisticada em qualquer uma delas. O que eu não faço é misturá-las sem necessidade.

Há um fenômeno no nosso meio (em qualquer um, claro) em que muita gente acha que sabe algo sem saber. Isso é chamado de [Efeito Dunning-Krugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect). É comum a pessoa não saber a matemática e o português básicos e achar que não é necessário para conseguir programar. A pessoa não tem entendimento lógico, não consegue interpretar texto, seguir instruções e ter discernimento de como adaptá-las, pesquisar informações, e mesmo assim sai gerando códigos. Então dê um desconto para a pessoa que comete esses erros de avaliação do que é uma coisa e o que é outra.

Quase todos os projetos complexos escritos em C que eu conheço funcionam perfeitamente em um compilador C++.

Se tiver perguntas mais específicas, pode fazer de forma clara.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Essa resposta só comprova que a pergunta do AP é justa. Pode ajudar muitos outros estudantes no futuro. :)

Comment: Valeu por especificar, matou todas minhas dúvidas, resolvi aprender C++ do zero, e to sentindo vantagens nisso, mas as vezes me deparo com pseudo códigos de C++ mas devo me acostumar aos poucos e entender o estilo do C++

Comment: C++ NÃO É SUPERCONJUNTO DE C. Vários códigos C não tem valia ou funcionam de maneira diferente em C++!

Comment: Sim, meia dúzia de coisas não funcionam bem, é que eu não quis ser pedante.